# Is .asc supported raster data source for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, esri-ascii-raster

I am new using QGIS and struggling with this error "...... .asc is not a supported raster data source" when trying to add a ."asc" file as a raster.

I downloaded the files from http://www.geog.mcgill.ca/landuse/pub/Data/175crops2000/ArcASCII-Zip/

I tried Layer: Add Raster Layer, and also Raster: Conversion: Translate (convert format)
but neither recognized the .asc

Comment: The format that you are probably looking at is [**Esri ASCII raster format**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Esri_ASCII_raster_format/009t0000000z000000/).  This [**wiki page**](http://wiki.tuflow.com/index.php?title=QGIS_Importing_a_Grid) suggests that importing into QGIS should be possible so perhaps open it up and see if it looks like it should.

Comment: It is mentioned in GDAL_Formats http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html#AAIGrid. Though I do remember having a problem previously; ensure your driver is set to AAIGrid and if that fails then use GDAL_Translate (find it in your QGIS install directory\bin) to convert to TIF or ERDAS Imagine.

Comment: Possible solution here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124797/why-cant-i-open-asc-files-in-qgis