# Opening.asc files in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, esri-ascii-raster

Further to [Where do I find the legend for netCDF files in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124783), I have .nc and .asc files of crop area and production for maize, rice and wheat. **[It says here](http://wiki.tuflow.com/index.php?title=QGIS_Importing_a_Grid)**, about QGIS importing .asc files:

> QGIS has native support for this format.   ESRI grid (.asc) files can
>   be directly opened in QGIS by selecting Layers >>> Add Raster Layer. 
>   The .asc file can also be dragged and dropped into the QGIS session, rather than using the Add Raster Layer option.

But when I do either, I get this error:

> .asc is not a supported raster data source.

which has been reported at [Is .asc supported raster data source for QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93678)

I am using version 2.0.1-Dufour.

Comment: it is a problem of GDAL. What is your OS (Windows, Linux, Mac) ? ([GDAL raster format](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html))

Comment: Windows 7,  8Gb RAM. But I just noticed something weird about these files. They're about 100 MB and they contain (looked with Textpad) nothing but endless rows of -9999.000, -9999.000, -9999.000 -9999.000 -9999.000.  Not sure what that means (oceans?). Got them from here: http://www.geog.mcgill.ca/landuse/pub/Data/175crops2000/ArcASCII-Zip/

Comment: Look at the header `NODATA_value  -9999.000`: there are empty asc files. The format is described in [ESRI grid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esri_grid)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just downloaded one of the files in the repository that you linked to (brazil_yield.asc) and tried to import the file into another GIS program. I also ran into an import error. I finally tracked the error down to an attempt to convert a blank cell to a numerical type. In other words, there are blanks in the file because they have been improperly formatted. Rewriting the import tool to ignore blank cells resulted in a successful import. There are several places in the file that have two spaces in a row. See the figure below.

[image]

For a proper space delimited file, there can only be one space between each number.

Comment: Well done, it works

Comment: Yes, scrolling (very slowly) with Textpad I noticed those odd spaces.

Comment: @plugincontainer You can probably just do a find and replace in textpad to replace the multiple spaces to a single space and it'll import successfully. Good luck.

Comment: Hey @WhiteboxDev - I tried global search-and-replace with Textpad, Word and OpenOfficeWriter and they can't handle that many replaces ("program is not responding"). Started doing it in blocks in Word and it's neverending - thousands of spaces to fix. Do you know how I can tell QGIS to do what you did, i.e. "ignore blank cells"?

Comment: @gene ... finally got rid of all double spaces. But QGIS won't accept it. What is the GDAL issue?

Comment: @plugincontainer Unfortunately I can't run the GDAL code to figure out where it isn't working but if Gene said that he got it to work on his computer than I'm sure it can be done. I was able to successfully import your file in the open source GIS Whitebox GAT, for which I am a developer, after having modified the Import ArcGIS ASCII Grid tool to handle the extra spaces. You can try that route if you like. Just install Whitebox, then right-click over the Import ArcGIS ASCII Grid tool in the Data Import/Export toolbox and select Update Script From Code Repository.

Comment: @WhiteboxDev In my 'problematic' file (see post below) there where multiple spaces. But this was not the problem to open the file. So I guess QGIS automatically ignores multiple spaces between the values.

Comment: @KalleBlomquist It's probably been fixed in a recent update. The answer is two years old now and I believe both GDAL and QGIS have been updated in that time.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS will not import ESRI ASCII format if the header contains leading whitespace of any kind.
Remove leading whitespace and QGIS will load the file correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar difficulties to import an ASCII file into QGIS. I opened it with a texteditor to have a look on it. There was a header with information about the author, coordinate system, etc. I removed this part, so that the file had the following [structure given from ESRI](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISengine/java/Gp_ToolRef/Spatial_Analyst_Tools/esri_ascii_raster_format.htm):

```
NCOLS 654
NROWS 866
XLLCORNER 3281000
YLLCORNER 5238000
CELLSIZE 1000
NODATA_VALUE -999
-999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999 ...
...
```

Finally, I was able to open the file in QGIS with 'Add Raster Layer'.